# Is there a way to apply numpy.extract to a 3d-array?

Tags: python, numpy, filter

I have the following:

```
X = np.ndarray (324,349,24)
y = np.ndarray (324,349)
```

I would like to create a dictionary to house conditional extraction, to wit:

```
myDict = {'keyA':cond,'keyB':cond,'keyC':cond,'keyD':cond}
```

Each key in myDict.keys() is represented numerically within *y*. What I would like to do is apply a mask and extract only those indices within *X* that correspond to the set mask.

For example,

*condA = y==0
...
condD = y==3*

How would I go about applying those condition on *X*? I was thinking something along these lines:

```py
for k in range(1, X.shape[2]):
  myDict['keyA'] = np.extract(condA,k)
  myDict['keyB'] = np.extract(condB,k)
  myDict['keyC'] = np.extract(condC,k)
  myDict['keyD'] = np.extract(condD,k)
```

However, I get the error:

```py
IndexError: index is out of bounds for size
```

Expected Output:
A dictionary:

```py
myDict{'keyA':ndarray [n,n,24],'keyB':ndarray[n,n,24],'keyC':ndarray[n,n,24],'keyD':ndarray[n,n,24]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The numpy function `where`may be useful here:

```
myDict['keyA'] = X.where(condA)
```